# Determine all $n$-digit numbers that are divisible by the cyclic permutations of its digits

Tags: number-theory, divisibility, decimal-expansion

> Given an integer $n \geq 2$, determine all $n$-digit numbers $M_0 = \overline{a_1a_2 \ldots a_n}$ $(a_i \neq 0, i = 1,2,\ldots,n)$ divisible by the numbers $M_1 = \overline{a_2a_3 \ldots a_na_1}$, $M_2 = \overline{a_3a_4\ldots a_na_1a_2},\ldots,M_{n-1} = \overline{a_na_1a_2 \ldots a_{n-1}}$.

We first note that $a_i \leq 4$ for $i > 1$ unless $a_1 = \cdots = a_n$ where $a_1 > 4$. Thus assuming that is not the case, $M_0 \leq \underbrace{84\ldots4}_{n-1 \text{ 4s}}$.

What do I do from here?

Comment: How do you get $a_i\le 4$?

Comment: @barto Because otherwise it would add another digit.

Comment: @user19405892: That does not make sense. _What_ would add another digit? Why and how would it do that? What does it even mean to "add another digit"?

Comment: It means that any multiple of such a number would have $n+1$ digits. Ok, but this only proves that $a_i\leq4$ for all $i>1$.

Comment: @barto: Oh, all right. So we do know that $a_i\le\lfloor a_1/2\rfloor$ for $i>1$, and also that if the number doesn't consists of multiple repeats of the same block we must have $n\le a_0-1$ (because $M/M_i$ must be $\le a_0$ if leading zeroes are to be avoided). That restricts the search space enough that a brute-force search seems feasible.

Comment: The $M_i$ are of the form $M_0/k$ for some $k\in\{1,\ldots,8\}$, so there are at most $8$ distinct numbers among them.

Comment: Brute-force programmed and run. There are no numbers satisfying my conditions above, _other than the repdigits_, where even $M_1$ divides $M_0$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm The only numbers that appear to work are $\overline{aa\ldots a}$?

Comment: @user19405892: Correct.

Comment: I don't understand why THE LARGEST DIGIT ONLY APPEARS ONCE.

Comment: @CarryonSmiling: The _first_ digit can appear only once, because if it appeared twice, then one of the other $M_i$s would start with the same digit, and that cannot be a divisor of $M_0$. Similarly, if one of the other digits were larger than the first, then that $M_i$ would be _larger than_ $M_0$ and so _certainly_ not a divisor.

Comment: can't it be equal to $M_0$ ?

Comment: @CarryonSmiling: That's a trivial case -- then $M_0$ would consist of a repetition of identical parts. So we get things like $33333333$ this way, but as long as the only numbers that can't be split are the single digits, that's _all_ we get.

Comment: ok, but then we would need to prove onlly the single digits cant be split.

Comment: Please edit the question to include additional context: where did the problem come from? What makes it interesting? What else would it help us understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $M_i = k_iM_0$ for $i = 1, 2, \cdots, n - 1$, and we let $k_0 = 1$. Since $a_i \neq 0$, so $k_i \neq 0$.

Case 1: if $k_i = k_j$ for some $i < j$. Claim: this will be reduced to the same question with $n' = j - i$.

Proof: Since $k_i = k_j$, so $M_i = M_j$. Denote $x = \overline{a_{i + 1} \cdots a_j}$, and $y = \overline{a_{j + 1} \cdots a_{j + n'}}$

$$
\overline{xa_{j + 1}a_{j + 2}\cdots} = M_i = M_j = \overline{ya_{j + n' + 1}a_{j + n' + 2}\cdots} \Rightarrow x = y
$$

Using the same argument shows that $M_i = \overline{xx \cdots xx}$, i.e. a repeating of the segment $x$. Then now $x$ (possibly a reordering of $x$) is a solution to the same problem for a smaller $n'$.

Case 2: if $k_i \neq k_j, \forall i$. Clearly $k_i < 10$ because of the number of digits. So $k_i \in \{1, \cdots, 9\}$. So $n \leq 9$. Claim: there is no solution.

Proof: We first claim that $a_1 = \max\{a_i\}$. If not, suppose $a_t > a_1$, then

$$
M_{t - 1} \leq k_{t - 1}M_{t - 1} = M_0 < (a_1 + 1)10^{n - 1} \leq a_t10^{n - 1} \leq M_{t - 1},
$$

a contradiction. Therefore $a_1 = \max\{a_i\}$. Then

$$
(\sum_{i = 0}^{n - 1}10^i)na_1 \geq (\sum_{i = 0}^{n - 1}10^i)(\sum_{i = 1}^na_i) = \sum_{i = 0}^{n - 1}M_i = (\sum_{i = 0}^{n - 1}k_i)M_0 \geq (\sum_{i = 0}^{n - 1}k_i)10^{n - 1}a_1 \geq (n + 1)10^{n - 1}a_1.
$$

Cancel $a_1$ on both sides of the inequality, we have

$$
(\sum_{i = 0}^{n - 1}10^i)n \geq (n + 1)10^{n - 1} \Rightarrow n \geq (\sum_{i = 1}^{n - 1}10^{-i})^{-1} > 9,
$$

a contradiction.

In conclusion, with only Case 1 possible, using induction on $n$, we will end up with the only solution $M_0 = \overline{aa\cdots aa}$.

Comment: Can you elaborate on case 1?

Comment: @Puzzled417 Compare $M_i$ and $M_j$ by each digit, you will find out that the segment $x$ repeats itself in $M_i$. But $M_i$ is just a reorder of $M_0$, so a reorder of $x$ will have the same property as described in the question.

Answer (score 2):

All repdigits work, of course. But those are the only solutions.

Let's consider just those numbers where $M_1$ divides $M_0$. We can then write
$$ M_0 = 10^{n-1}a + b \qquad\qquad M_1 = 10b+a $$
where $a$ is a single digit and all the other digits are in $b$. This means that for some $k\in\{2,3,\ldots,8\}$ we must have
$$ 10^{n-1}a + b = k(10b+a) $$
which can be solve for $b$ to give
$$ \tag{*} b = \frac{a(10^{n-1}-k)}{10k-1} $$
Furthermore $n$ can be at least $8$; otherwise $M_0$ would be made of repeats of a single digit sequence that in itself would satisfy the condition.

So all in all there are only $9\times 7\times 7=441$ combinations of $a$, $k$, $n$ to try -- a quick computer search shows that $b$ is an integer only for these 10 solutions:

```
102564/4 = 25641
205128/4 = 51282
307692/4 = 76923
410256/4 = 102564
512820/4 = 128205
615384/4 = 153846
717948/4 = 179487
714285/5 = 142857
820512/4 = 205128
923076/4 = 230769
```

and it is easy to see that for each of these one of the other $M_i$s will fail to divide $M_0$.

Comment: "Furthermore n can be at least 8; otherwise M0 would be made of repeats of a single digit sequence that in itself would satisfy the condition." could you explain this?

Comment: @CarryonSmiling: Haven't we just been through this? Each of the $M_i$s must be one of $M_0, M_0/2, M_0/3, \ldots, M_0/8$, and if two of them are equal, then the entire $M_0$ is a repeat.

Comment: a repeat of what exactly?

Comment: @CarryonSmiling: A repeat of some sequence of digits that would in itself be a solution to the problem.

Comment: Are you sure, I don't see exactly why the sequence which is to be repeated must also be a solution.

Comment: @CarryonSmiling: If each $M_i$ consists of two or more repetitions of the same digits, and you multiply it by some $k$, then there can't be a carry out of the rightmost copy of the sequence, because then there would be a carry out of _each_ copy of the sequence, especially the leftmost one, which would make $k\cdot M_i$ have too many digits to equal $M_0$. We conclude that there are no carries between the copy, suych that $k$ times the leftmost part equals the matching leftmost part of $M_0$.

Comment: oh ok, got it thanks, it would also suffice to bruteforce all number under $10$ digits right?